# Flutter staggered gridview with draggable tiles

Tags: flutter, drag-and-drop, resize, staggered-gridview

I am looking for a layout that looks similar to staggered grid view but with tiles that can be re-sizable and re-ordered (draggable). Any thoughts, how this can be achieved?

something like this: http://hootsuite.github.io/grid/

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/drag_and_drop_gridview

Comment: I want this in a staggered grid

Comment: @ChandrakantSabnavis have you find the way for this?